# Javascript function add value in other html page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function productID(id)
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = id;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="page.html"><img src="...images/car.jpg" onclick="productID('1')"></a>
</body>
```

When the user click on the image:
1) A new page open
2) The javascript function search for the first form field input in the page and write in it the `productID`

My question is:
How can I let this function write the `productID` in the first form field input in `page.html` that the user is already moved to it when he clicked on the image?
not in the same page!

Comment: So you're asking how to pass data between pages? You may want to try to search for that. There's lots of questions that deal with this.

Comment: you would need to either 1. use a server sided language such as PHP to handle a GET or POST request or 2. just send them to a new page with a get request (eg: `page.html?productID=1`) and manually retrieve the get request using javascript, although I would recommend using method 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a reference to the document or window of `page.html`. If you opened the link with, for example: `window.open` you would. This means you can't do it with JavaScript.

You can do it with the use of a server side scripting language.